# SQL Server parsing function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split Function equivalent in tsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)

I have a column that contains data in the form:

```
CustomerZip::12345||AccountId::1111111||s_Is_Advertiser::True||ManagedBy::3000||CustomerID::5555555||
```

Does SQL have any sort of built in function to easily parse out this data, or will I have to build my own complicated mess of patindex/substring functions to pull each value into its own field?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722700/how-do-i-split-a-delimited-string-in-sql-server-without-creating-a-function

Comment: This blog post may also help: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything built in. Look at the comments posted against your original question.

If this is something you're going to need on a regular basis, consider writing a view.