# SQL: Select values from a list of values in separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I give this query: 
`select 'a', 'b'`

I get the output:

```
-------------------------------------
|(No column name) | (No column name)|
-------------------------------------
|       a         |        b        |
-------------------------------------
```

But I want the results(a and b) to be in separate rows.

Could someone please explain me or give sample query to attain this?

Comment: Whats the database you are using? MS SQL Server, MYSQL etc..?

Comment: I am using an MS SQL db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to change your query to use union.

Query:

```
 select 'a'
 union all
 select 'b'
```

Comment: Is this the only possible way? Creating as many select statements as the number of values I have?

Comment: No, you can do it in different values. is your values coming from a table or how its defined?

Comment: I get the values from an external file.

Comment: You can pass the values from external file as some delimited text example: comma and use the logic mentioned in this post to split it as rows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722700/how-do-i-split-a-delimited-string-in-sql-server-without-creating-a-function

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using MS SQL Server you can use UNPIVOT operator to do what you want,

Have a look at this article : 
http://tuvianblog.com/2012/07/12/how-to-unpivot-table-in-sql-server-unpivot-table-example-in-sql-server/

Comment: Whats your original table structure?