# Insert query where one field is a dynamic list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to solve the challenge of having an insert query where action_key is a dynamic list of strings. The cust_name and action fields will be the same for each new row, but action_key will change depending on how many action keys are in the list. Example:

```
INSERT INTO [table_name] (cust_name, action, action_key) VALUES (Bob, Approve, ApproveId1)
INSERT INTO [table_name] (cust_name, action, action_key) VALUES (Bob, Approve, ApproveId2) etc.
```

I'd appreciate some insight on this topic, thanks.

Comment: So the inputs would be 'Johnny Construction', 'ChargeAccount', 'Wood|Cement|Nails|Tools' and you would want to insert four rows into [table_name] with 'Johnny Construction' and 'ChargeAccount' for the cust_name and action respectively for all four rows and 'Wood','Cement','Nails' and 'Tools' broken into their own rows?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct.

Comment: What's the delimiter for action_key?

Comment: list: would it represent table or a parameter?

Comment: you can try insert into select with cross apply on split function that splits your action_key to tabular data

Comment: Its coming in as a SOAP response, so something like:
<actionKeys>
    <actionKey>yada yada</actionKey>...etc.
</actionKeys>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to play with it, but based upon your XML structure input that's how I handled the parsing.

```
Declare @cust_name Varchar(50),
        @action Varchar(50),
        @action_key Varchar(1000)

Select  @cust_name = 'Bob',
        @action = 'Approve',
        @action_key = '<action_keys><action_key>ApproveId1</action_key><action_key>ApproveId2</action_key><action_key>ApproveId3</action_key><action_key>ApproveId4</action_key></action_keys>'


Select  @cust_name,
        @action,
        n.r.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
From   (Select  Cast(@action_key As Xml)) As s(XMLCol)
Cross   Apply s.XMLCol.nodes('action_keys/action_key') as n(r)
```

Reference: [How Do I Split a Delimited String in SQL Server Without Creating a Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722700/how-do-i-split-a-delimited-string-in-sql-server-without-creating-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't say *how* you get the list of strings, but generally you could create a SQL string dynamically and execute it:

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO [table_name] ' +
      '(cust_name, action, ' + action_key + ') ' + 
      'VALUES (''Bob'', ''Approve'', ''ApproveId1'')')
```

Comment: The list would come in as a C# string list.