# Unable to retrieve a column no XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, split

I have the problem to retrieve a column that is not XML. I received the following solution to my previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761742/how-to-split-a-string-to-rows-in-sql-without-function/50762394?noredirect=1#comment88725796_50762394). I added a column that I need to retrieve for the SQL, PM column. Every time that I run the query, I received the error invalid column name PM. What am I missing to retrieve the column PM?

```
DECLARE @Tabaldata TABLE ( data nvarchar(max), PM nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @Tabaldata
SELECT 
'Technology|faa5d304-f2d1-42c3-8d21-e87697b42bdc;Application|56b19e9a-e58a-4c79-a518-b129fb5f499f;Database
|d7425391-8f8c-4aec-be04-9caf2f55584a;Mobile/BYOD|8f0f30e7-d16d-48a3-ad82-cfdd39156760;Networking
|3876dbd8-8cd8-4040-9c67-0633f8477f93;Operating System|10fc2ce4-53fd-4af2-8fd9-9df66a38715f;Reporting|
00307182-43f4-4bbf-9a95-cd8dbf59754a;Security|014e8d4d-4fd9-404c-8db8-13e84c9042fe;User Interface|57d65a47-6ad2-4df7-8d36-acdf3e0a3145;Web Tech|1b9e82eb-5f70-4183-9093-5', 'Testing Project'


SELECT data ActualData, 
        SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX(';' ,data)+1,LEN(data)) AS ExpectedData
FROM
(
    SELECT Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(max)') data
    FROM(
    SELECT CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(data,'|','</S><S>')+'</S>'  AS XML) data
    FROM @Tabaldata
    )AS A 
    CROSS APPLY data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)dt
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',(SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX(';' ,data)+1,LEN(data))))=0
```

Comment: Works on my machine.

Comment: Could you retrieve both columns?

Comment: Yes, ActualData and ExpectedData. No errors. SQL Server 2016 vis SSMS.

Comment: I could finally run the column PM. Thanks Dan Wilson

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Tabaldata TABLE ( data nvarchar(max), PM nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @Tabaldata
SELECT 
'Technology|faa5d304-f2d1-42c3-8d21-e87697b42bdc;Application|56b19e9a-e58a-4c79-a518-b129fb5f499f;Database
|d7425391-8f8c-4aec-be04-9caf2f55584a;Mobile/BYOD|8f0f30e7-d16d-48a3-ad82-cfdd39156760;Networking
|3876dbd8-8cd8-4040-9c67-0633f8477f93;Operating System|10fc2ce4-53fd-4af2-8fd9-9df66a38715f;Reporting|
00307182-43f4-4bbf-9a95-cd8dbf59754a;Security|014e8d4d-4fd9-404c-8db8-13e84c9042fe;User Interface|57d65a47-6ad2-4df7-8d36-acdf3e0a3145;Web Tech|1b9e82eb-5f70-4183-9093-5', 'Testing Project'


SELECT PM, data ActualData, 
        SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX(';' ,data)+1,LEN(data)) AS ExpectedData
FROM
(
    SELECT PM, Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(max)') data
    FROM(
    SELECT PM, CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(data,'|','</S><S>')+'</S>'  AS XML) data
    FROM @Tabaldata
    )AS A 
    CROSS APPLY data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)dt
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',(SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX(';' ,data)+1,LEN(data))))=0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to split both in one go:

```
SELECT PM, CAST('<S><x>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(data,'|','</x><x>'),';','</x></S><S><x>')+'</x></S>'  AS XML) data
FROM @Tabaldata
```

This leads to

```
<S>
  <x>Technology</x>
  <x>faa5d304-f2d1-42c3-8d21-e87697b42bdc</x>
</S>
<S>
  <x>Application</x>
  <x>56b19e9a-e58a-4c79-a518-b129fb5f499f</x>
</S>
... more of them ...
```

With a query like this

```
SELECT s.value('x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS KeyName
      ,s.value('x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS KeyValue --you might use "uniqueidentifier" to get it typed, but all values must be GUIDs in this case...
FROM
(
    SELECT PM, CAST('<S><x>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(data,'|','</x><x>'),';','</x></S><S><x>')+'</x></S>'  AS XML) data
    FROM @Tabaldata
) AS casted
CROSS APPLY casted.data.nodes(N'/S') AS A(s)
```

You get this

```
KeyName           KeyValue
Technology        faa5d304-f2d1-42c3-8d21-e87697b42bdc
Application       56b19e9a-e58a-4c79-a518-b129fb5f499f
Database          d7425391-8f8c-4aec-be04-9caf2f55584a
...more of them...
```